# 'Too few arguments' - I can't use the given Values in the Object to use Class Functions

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Hello and thank you for your time.

Im a beginner so it is prbly pretty obvious, sorry but I can't figure it out for myself... :(

On my assignment, they ask me to build this program and test the functions in the Class banderas_Triang. As you can see, they way im trying to do it is to build a Class Object and give it some parameters like this:

```
banderas_Triang triang1(50, 50, 50);
```

After that, I want to test the function called arTriang(); With the values entered above...

So I go like this:

```
cout << banderas_triang.triang1();
```

And here is where I get the error... It says 'too few arguments'. I know that it means I should put values in the () of the function. But I want to use the ones I gave the Obj triang1.

How can I use the parameters entered in the triang1 and calculate stuff like the area with the functions of the class?

Pbly my code is laughable, sorry it's my first project...I just cant seem to make it work...

Heres the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class bandera_Triang {
private:
    float aSide, bSide, cSide;

public:
    bandera_Triang(){ //Cost. sin Param...
        aSide = 0;
        bSide = 0;
        cSide = 0;
    }
    bandera_Triang(float A, float B, float C){ //Const. con Param...
        aSide = A;
        bSide = B;
        cSide = C;
    }

    //Sets...
    void set_A(float A){ aSide = A; }
    void set_B(float B){ bSide = B; }
    void set_C(float C){ cSide = C; }

    //Gets...
    float get_A(){ return aSide; }
    float get_B(){ return bSide; }
    float get_C(){ return cSide; }

    //~bandera_Triang();



    bool esTriang(){ //Desigualdad Triangular...
        if (aSide < bSide + cSide && bSide < aSide + cSide && cSide < aSide + bSide) {
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }

    string triangOno(bool esTriang()){ //Print si es o no triangulo...
        if (esTriang() == true){
            return "Es Triangulo.";
        }
        else { return "NO es Triangulo."; }
    }

    string tipoTriang(){
        if (aSide == bSide && bSide == cSide){
            return "El triangulo es Equilatero.";
        }
        else
        if (aSide == bSide || aSide == cSide || bSide == cSide){
            return "El triangulo es Isosceles. ";
        }
        return "El triangulo es Escaleno.";
    }

    float arTriang(float aSide, float bSide, float cSide){ //Area Triangulo con F.Heron.

        float SemiPerim = 0;
        float areaTriang = 0; //Variables locales para calculo.

        SemiPerim = (aSide + bSide + cSide) / 2; //Calculo de Semiperimetro.

        areaTriang = sqrt((SemiPerim * (SemiPerim -aSide) * (SemiPerim - bSide) * (SemiPerim - cSide)));

        return areaTriang;
    }


}; //Fin Clase Triangulo



//Inicia Main

int main(){
    bandera_Triang triangA(50, 50, 50); //this should pass the given values to
                                        // the class triangle so it can do things...


    cout << triangA.arTriang(); //it should calc the triangles area, instead it tells me 'too few
                                // arguments... what am i doing wrong?



    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: `arTriang` requires three arguments but you aren't passing any at all.

Comment: Side note: The site guidelines for posting a question here are that it is posted **in English**. Although not mandatory, it is highly recommended that you apply this on your **coding comments** as well. Readers are expected to be fluent in the programming language or languages that the question is tagged under, **not** in your native language (whatever that is).

Comment: What is the correct way to call the function arTriang then?
Isnt there a way to use the values i gave the object triang1?
(50, 50, 50)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're really close!

Since `arTriang` is a *member function*, it already has access to the *member* variables of the object on which you call it. It seems to me that it shouldn't take any arguments, but should use those member variables instead.

Your call would then be correct as-is.

Comment: Hi, ma'am... Thank you for the answer... 

But I still dont get it. 

How can I pass the values given in:
`bandera_Triang triang1 (50, 50, 50);`  
It works if I do this:

`cout<< banderas_triang.arTriang(50,50,50);`
But what im trying to do is to set the values of the object to 50, 50 and 50. And after that make the functions work the stuff...

Thanks...

Comment: @DanielSegura: You don't need to pass them; they're already there, in the object. Hint: you already used them properly in `esTriang()`.

Comment: Then why do I get the error :(

Error 1 error C3867: 'bandera_Triang::arTriang': function call missing argument list; use '&bandera_Triang::arTriang' to create a pointer to member.

Comment: @DanielSegura: Because you didn't do as I told you.

Comment: OMG I think i get it... Thank you for a lot for the insight...  the class function should be `arTriang (){ //stuff...}` IT WORKED. 
I cant stress how thankful I am, ma'am. 
:')